# Characterization of continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ - Proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

I try to prove the following characterization of continuity:

> Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f([c,d])$ is connected for all $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$. Then $f$ is continuous  on $[a,b]$

I reasoned in the following way: Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at $p\in [a,b]$. So for some $\varepsilon_0$ we have $f([a,b]\cap (f(p)-\varepsilon_0,f(p)+\varepsilon_0) =\{f(p)\}$. But then, if there are any point $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)>f(p)$ or $f(x)<f(p)$. This would lead to a contradiction since $f([x,p])$ is an interval. So this means that $f$ is constant which is contradiction. 
I am aware that there are similar questions in this platform, however, I seem to be missing the need for the first requirement in my proof. So my question is that is the proof valid? If so, where should I use the fact that $f^{-1}(\{y\}$ closed for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Many thanks!

Comment: The hypothesis that $f$ is discontinuous at $p$ does not, by itself, imply that $f([a,b])\cap (-e+f(p),e+f(p)\})=\{f(p)\}$ for some $e>0.$.... For example, with $a<b$ and $p=a$ let  $f(p)=b-a$ and $f(x)=x-a$ for $x\in (a,b]$..... Then for $ e>0 $ we have $f([a,b])\cap (-e+f(p),e+f(p))=$ $(0,b-a]\cap (-e+b-a,e+b-a)=$ $=( \;\max (0,-e+b-a),\; b-a]$ which is an interval of non-zero length.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof has an unwarranted assumption, as I pointed out in my comment to the Q.

Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at $p.$ Then WLOG there is an $r>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[a,b]$ converging to $p$, with $x_n<p$ and $f(x_n)<f(p)-r$ for every $n.$

Now $f([x_n,p])$ is connected so $f([x_n,p])\supset [f(x_n),f(p)]\supset [-r+f(p),f(p)]$. So there exists $y_n\in (x_n,p)$ with $f(y_n)=-r+f(p).$

But $(y_n)_n$ converges to $p$ while $\{y_n\}_n$ is a subset of the closed set $f^{-1}\{-r+f(p)\},$ implying $p\in f^{-1}\{-r+f(p)\}.$ That is, $f(p)=-r+f(p)<f(p),$ which is absurd.

Comment: I don't understand what $x$ means in the first paragraph of your proof.

Comment: I think that should read as $p$.

Comment: @murray. I must have missed a typo. I often do.